# Как можно скачивать файлы с сайта в цикле и загружать их в один архив?

Tags: python, requests, zipfile

У меня есть сайт, с которого я перебором ссылки выгружаю все файлы. Мне нужно все эти файла заливать в один архив, подскажите как это реализовать.
На данном этапе код следующий:

```
import requests
import zipfile
import time
import ssl

def tets():
    url_num = 0
    for i in range(1, 100):
        url = 'http://site.com/files/download_file/{}'.format(url_num)
        url_num += i
        r = requests.get(url, verify=ssl.CERT_NONE, timeout=10, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            with zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\backup\\delete\\test.zip", "w") as myzip:
                myzip.write(r.content)
                myzip.close()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                print(f'Документ {i} скачан.')
        else:
            continue
    print(f'Все документы загружены. Последний документ: {i}')
```

Выдает ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myzip.write` ожидает на вход имя файла для добавления в архив. Вы можете сохранять что скачали во временный файл, а уже этот файл добавлять в архив.